# Check whether $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification

> Let $\Bbb{Q}=\{q_1,q_2,q_3,\cdots\}$ be enumeration of rationals. Define $$f(x)=\displaystyle \sum_{q_i<x}2^{-i}$$
>   Investigate whether $f$ is continuous on $\Bbb{R}$. And is $f$ differentiable at other points?

I think it will be discontinuous at each $q_i$, as $f(q_i+)-f(q_i-)=2^{-i}$ so that $f$ has jump discontinuities at each $q_i$ and if we consider the quotient at each continuity point $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$$ then numerator is some finite sum whereas denominator is going to 0, thus derivative won't exists.

Comment: You're definitely right about the jump discontinuity at $q_i$. The differentiability question is more subtle. What do you mean by “numerator is some finite sum”? It is in fact a sum of infinitely many numbers, but goes to zero as $h\to0$.

Comment: It's a good exercise to write down a rigorous proof that the jump discontinuity at $q_i$ is exactly $2^{-i}$ and no greater.

Comment: @HaraldHanche-Olsen what will be the rigorous proof for differentiability?

Comment: I haven't tried it, for lack of time. Possibly someone will come up with an answer.